# How can I simplify this highly nested data structure?

Tags: information-architecture, tabs, categorization

I have this data structure

```
Category 1 
    Sub Category 1 
          Medium 1 
              Language 1 
              Language 2 
          Medium 2 
              Language 1 
              Language 2 
Category 2 
    Sub Category 2 
          Medium 1 
              Language 1 
              Language 2 
          Medium 2 
              Language 1 
              Language 2
```

I have selected the ux in the image, Is there a way to simplify it ? [image]

Comment: Can we assume, as in your example, that each of your categories only ever contains one sub-category? If so, then you can combine them and remove a tier of the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, they are.  Very valid suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Trying to layer multiple levels of tab controls can get messy, fast.

I would suggest you stick with something more simple such as a navigation menu. You could also make it an accordion menu if you don't want all sub-categories to be visible at the same time.

Here is an example of a simple menu:

[image]

It isn't clear what "medium" and "language" are in your question. So this idea works on the basis that they are field sets and fields. Therefore, you have the navigation menu for categories, and then a single (scrollable) view that will hold all the data for the selected sub-category.

Comment: Sub menus are a great idea. And if it's possible, make some sensible choices for the user so they don't have to.